# React app that is white labelled and wanting to switch labels based off the URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, white-labelling

I have a react web app that is white labelled and there are 4 versions out there. The code is completely parameterised so all I have to do is change one value in the app and then it will connect to the correct AWS Cognito for the auth and then the correct database etc...

Each of the 4 versions is on its own unique domain, which uses CloudFront and an S3 bucket to host. So I have 4 S3 buckets, and each time I make a code change I have to compile 4 times (each time changing the one parameter) and do 4 uploads etc... and this will obviously blow out as more get deployed over time.

What I want to do is make it so I only have to compile once and use one S3 bucket to save time. I was thinking of grabbing the URL and then depending on what the URL is, to change that one parameter in the code that I was previously changing manually for the label before I compile. But I don't know if this is bad practice or if there is a better way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One option I could think of : use header parameter with application id in every request. Based on application id , load the necessary application specific properties like Cognito etc in the back-end.

Comment: do you mean to pass something from the cloudfront to the react app? if so how do you do this? If not can you explain your answer a little bit more as I'm not understanding? Thank you.

Comment: Have a Lambda at Edge where based on the url , add the necessary header parameters , in this instance, application id.  One example of using Lambda at Edge shown  here https://www.jtouzi.net/adding-cors-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/

Comment: What is the difference between having lambda edge adding the parameters based on the url, vs looking up the url directly from the react code/app?